# 'In real life' or 'In person' in this case?

Tags: word-choice, difference

> I've never seen a comet **in real life/person**; only in photographs.

'In person', in this case, would mean that the viewer is present to witness the passing of a comet with his or her own eyes.

'In real life' emphasizes the fact that it was a real experience, perhaps also hinting that it can't have been touched up like a photograph.

I'm not sure which of the two fits this sentence best. I was wondering if there may be even better options.

Comment: I would choose _in real life_, otherwise it sounds as though you are calling the comet a person!

Comment: @kate, I disagree, I think "in person" is often used to mean the actor is physically present, indeed I use it that way myself.

Comment: @DavidSiegel As you say, TheFreeDicitonary (https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+person) confirms what you say. Still, using it for a comet does sound a little strange. It's like 'in person' requires some sort of vicinity. That's also why I wasn't sure about using it in this case.

Comment: @kate I have used "in person" for tyhings seem stargacing through a telescope, as opposed to things seen in pictured. Perhaps others would not use it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences:

> - I've never seen a comet in real life; only in photographs.
> - I've never seen a comet in person; only in photographs.

are grammatically valid and natural, a fluent speaker might say or write either. The meanings are very similar, and many readers would not take note of any difference.  The one using "in person" emphasizes the physical presnece of the speaker (or author), the other emphasizes that a photo is less "real" than a physical observation.

One might also use a phrase such as "in the sky" or "with my own eyes" instead. The difference is on of style, and the speaker or writer should chooe the foirm that best fits the rest of the text and its purpose.